# how to call PowerShell script with a GithubActions workflow?

Tags: powershell, github-actions

I'm calling `.\build.ps1` and it seems to hang:

https://github.com/nblockchain/ZXing.Net.Xamarin/runs/232358091

Do I need something special? In AzureDevOps this was working out of the box.

Comment: Not sure if you have to [specify shell to be run](https://help.github.com/en/articles/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#using-a-specific-shell) but I'm currently experiencing similar issue with my action (bash script). Already opened a ticket, but it's yet to be processed.

Comment: that was it, please post it as an answer and will upvote

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As agreed in the comments, the solution for this issue was to specify the shell to be run in your Action file. In your case you had to change from:

```
    - name: Build
      run: |
        .\build.ps1
```

to:

```
    - name: Build
      shell: pwsh
      run: |
        .\build.ps1
```

For more details about available values for `shell` param, refer to [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsshell).

Comment: The example with `shell: pwsh` is equivalent. The default shell for windows is `pwsh`, thus it is not necessary to specify it.

Comment: @MircoT and it's still required to be specified for non-Windows

Comment: Yes, but the workflow mentioned in the question was already windows-latest. This is why I don't understand the suggestion...

Comment: I think what happens is that when @Robert answered this question in 2019, `pwsh` was not the default back then

Comment: I tried with a self runner windows 2019 and got error as pwsh: command not found

Comment: @encryptedname make sure powershell 7 is installed on that machine

Comment: it is default runner available by github workflows, any specific preconfiguration we need to set for achieving this?